# Graceful shutdown on traefik

Tags: docker, traefik

I have a project running traefik, but i am having some problems about my updates. I am having Bad Gateway responses on deploy.

So I was searching about graceful shutdown and didnt find nothing conclusive, despite the link above:
https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/#transport

Does anybody know how should work on traefik?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about updating a container where you have a short timeframe during which the new container is not yet up and you are getting `Bad Gateway`?

In that case you can start up a new container, leave the old one running, wait for a few seconds and only then shutdown the old container by using a loadbalancer (https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/#servers-load-balancer).

The more information you give us the better we can help you...

Comment: hummm, kind of that, i need to test it!

Comment: You might want to look at this article: https://www.maxcountryman.com/articles/zero-downtime-deployments-with-docker-compose